# What version of "mysql-connector-java" to include in pom.xml for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql, maven-3

The mysql server version installed is `5.5.38` as verified by

```
sanchit@sanchit-3560:/$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

But in the [official maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) repository page the latest version is `5.1.32`. I think these versions are for MySQL installed in windows.

Which version of `mysql-connector-java` should I use in `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Versions should not coincide

This is the two different project **[MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/en/news-5-1.html)** and **[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/)**.

In my case MySQL version is:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2

and `mysql-connector-java`:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>5.1.28</version>
</dependency>
```

#### And that's work well!